# `Autodesk.Viewing.ScreenShot.getScreenShotWithBounds` uses viewer's default camera dimensions instead of bounds

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

Following [this advice](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/more-screenshots) I am trying to replace our usage of `viewer::getScreenshot` with `Autodesk.Viewing.ScreenShot.getScreenShotWithBounds`  which calls `Autodesk.Viewing.ScreenShot.getScreenShot` to support larger screenshots. However, the bounds are ignored. The behaviour seems to be that it makes a screenshot of the viewer's default camera or corresponding to its dimensions. Then it stretches the image to fit the given width and height. I expected the function to return a screenshot of the elements inside the given bounding box.

Is the function `getScreenShotWithBounds` supposed to do something different from what I am assuming?

Example code (LMV 7.40.0):

```js
const bbounds: THREE.Bbox3; // calculated for some elements I want to screenshot

Autodesk.Viewing.ScreenShot.getScreenShotWithBounds(NOP_VIEWER, Math.ceil(bbounds.size().x * 4), Math.ceil(bbounds.size().y* 4), (blob) => window.open(blob), {bounds: bbounds, margin: 0});
```

#### Manual screenshot of the viewer

[image]

#### Returned image of getScreenShotWithBounds

[image]

### Update:

I misunderstood the function. `Autodesk.Viewing.ScreenShot.getScreenShotWithBounds` just fits the bounds into the camera view. The bounds are not used for any cropping. See [my more detailed answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67702778/4295853).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The given width and height of `Autodesk.Viewing.ScreenShot.getScreenShotWithBounds` must be of the same aspect ratio as the viewer (see [Adam Nagy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67686057/4295853)), i.e.:

`getScreenShotWithBounds(NOP_VIEWER, NOP_VIEWER.getDimensions().width * 4, NOP_VIEWER.getDimensions().height * 4, options);`

`getScreenShotWithBounds` just fits the bounds into the camera view (internally it calls `viewer.navigation.fitBounds(true, bounds, false);`). The bounds are not used for any kind of cropping / pixel calculation or otherwise.

To get a specific aspect ratio by cropping, you have to provide `getCropBounds` in the `options` parameter.

For example to force a aspect ratio by cropping:

```js
getCropBounds: function(viewer: Autodesk.Viewing.Viewer3D, camera: Autodesk.Viewing.UnifiedCamera, bounds: THREE.Box3): THREE.Box2 {
 // calculate the crop bounds in pixels
 // if the crop bounds are larger the screenshot's width / height is taken
 const aspectRatio = new THREE.Vector2(4, 3);

 const viewerBoundsWidthRatio =  width / aspectRatio.x;
 const viewerBoundsHeightRatio = height / aspectRatio.y;

 const cropToHeight = viewerBoundsWidthRatio > viewerBoundsHeightRatio;
 const smallerScaleRatio = cropToHeight ? viewerBoundsHeightRatio : viewerBoundsWidthRatio;

 const cropBoundsSize = aspectRatio.clone().multiplyScalar(smallerScaleRatio);
 const cropBounds = new THREE.Box2(new THREE.Vector2(0, 0), new THREE.Vector2(cropBoundsSize.x, cropBoundsSize.y));
                                            
 const offset = cropToHeight ? new THREE.Vector2((width - cropBoundsSize.x) / 2, 0) : new THREE.Vector2(0, (height - cropBoundsSize.y) / 2);
 cropBounds.min.add(offset);
 cropBounds.max.add(offset);

return cropBounds;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The squashed image you are getting is suggesting it, but it's not clear from the comments in the [source code](https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/viewers/7.*/viewer3D.js), that you should keep the ratio of the **Viewer** for the `width` and `height` input parameters. So you should **only scale** them depending on your needs: `getScreenShotWithBounds(NOP_VIEWER, viewer_width * x, viewer_height * x, etc`

Then the `bounds` in the `options` should take care of the cropping.

Comment: Ah, I really misunderstood the function. The camera for the screenshots get fits the bounds into the camera and then takes the screenshot. To get the right aspect ratio I had to prodive the `getCropBounds` in the `options` parameter.